# How to test a function that is not returned in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, function

I am trying to test this function (listed below). In my test file I have:
     `var returnedId = cmCustomerDelegate.trimWorkStationId(workstationId);`
but `returnedID` is `undefined`. How can I call this function without changing the function structure itself?

```
angular.module('cmApp').factory('cmCustomerDelegate', [
    '$http',
    '$q',
    'GENERAL_CONFIG',
    '$rootScope',
    '$window',
    'logService',
    function ($http, $q, GENERAL_CONFIG, $rootScope, $window, logService) {
        var workStationId = $rootScope.decryptedValues.workStationId 

        //To trim the workstation Id off the starting element 'R' and last 4 elements '0101' - Example - RABCD1230101 becomes ABCD123
        function trimWorkStationId(workStationId){
            return workStationID
        }

        workStationId = trimWorkStationId(workStationId);

        return {
          //other functions are in here that can be called easily
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Why is your factory returning an empty object? Where are you inserting the test file? How are you trying to call the function? Try narrowing your code down to a small example showing everything relevant and people might be able to help you. In the current state, it is hard to answer the question

Comment: @LionC In the return block there are more functions being returned that can be called using the format cmDelegate.functionName(). but that function is located outside of the return and not sure if it is possible to call it